# Use max() function to get keys of dict items with max length

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have two dictionaries like so:

```
concave relations : {6: [2, 3, 4, 5], 2: [6], 3: [6], 4: [6], 5: [6]} 

convex relations : {1: [2, 3, 4, 5], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [1, 2, 4], 4: [1, 3, 5], 5: [1, 2, 4], 6: [7, 8, 9, 10], 7: [6, 8, 10, 11], 8: [6, 7, 9, 11], 9: [6, 8, 10, 11], 10: [6, 7, 9, 11], 11: [7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Previously I could find the key which corresponds to the item of max length using this code:

```
bottom_face = max(concave, key=lambda x:len(concave[x]))
```

Since the concave dict doesn't contain any items of the same length

Since this is not the case in the convex dict, and I want to return all of the keys which have max length items, I tried using the following:

```
possible_top_faces = [i for i, x in enumerate(convex) if x == max(convex, key=lambda x:len(convex[x]))]
```

But it is just returning:

```
[0]
```

Instead of the keys `1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the largest length of any key in `convex`, and use that as your standard for filtering out other keys in `convex`:

```
convex = {
    1: [2, 3, 4, 5], 
    2: [1, 3, 5], 
    3: [1, 2, 4], 
    4: [1, 3, 5], 
    5: [1, 2, 4], 
    6: [7, 8, 9, 10], 
    7: [6, 8, 10, 11], 
    8: [6, 7, 9, 11], 
    9: [6, 8, 10, 11], 
    10: [6, 7, 9, 11], 
    11: [7, 8, 9, 10]
}

longest_len = max(map(len, convex.values()))
max_lens = [k for k, v in convex.items() if len(v) == longest_len]
print(max_lens) # [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. That's much cleaner. Updated.

Comment: Make sure you absolutely don't fold the `longest_len` computation into the list comprehension filter clause, because that would re-traverse `convex` on every iteration of the comprehension.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's a good point, and why I avoided re-computing `longest_len` in my ` list comprehension.